# WinJS listview iteminvokedHanlder how to

Tags: javascript, listview, winjs, invoke

I'm using the iteminvokedHandler and was wonder if there is a better way to interact with the listView.

Currently using this:

```js
        WinJS.UI.processAll(root).then(function () {

            var listview = document.querySelector('#myNotePad').winControl;
            listview.addEventListener("iteminvoked", itemInvokedHandler,false);

            function itemInvokedHandler(e) {

                e.detail.itemPromise.done(function (invokedItem) {

                    myEdit();

                });
            };


        });
```

The problem is that everytime I click on the listview myEdit() is run and propagates within the listview. I was wondering how to do it once and stop invoking listview until I am done with myEdit? Is there a simpler way to handle such a situation as this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple yet hard to see when you have a mind block and forget some of the basics (yes yes I'm still learning):

```js
 var testtrue = true;      

       WinJS.UI.processAll(root).then(function () {

            var listview = document.querySelector('#myNotePad').winControl;
            listview.addEventListener("iteminvoked", itemInvokedHandler,false);

            function itemInvokedHandler(e) {

                e.detail.itemPromise.done(function (invokedItem) {

                  if (testtrue === true){

                    myEdit();

                  }  


                });
            };


        });
```

In myEdit:

```js
    function myEdit() {

        var theelem = document.querySelector(".win-selected #myNotes");

        var gestureObject = new MSGesture();  
        gestureObject.target = theelem;
        theelem.gestureObject = gestureObject;

        theelem.addEventListener("pointerdown", pointerDown, false);

        theelem.addEventListener("MSGestureHold", gestureHold, false);


        function pointerDown(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.target.gestureObject.addPointer(e.pointerId);
        }


        function gestureHold(e) {

            if (e.detail === e.MSGESTURE_FLAG_BEGIN && test === true) {
                e.preventDefault();
                    editNotes();

              } else {


                }

            console.log(e);
        }

        theelem.addEventListener("contextmenu", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();}, false); //Preventing system menu

    };


    function editNotes() {

      //The Code I wish to execute

        return test = false;
    };
```

What I needed was a conditional statement so that it would run if true and not if false. That same test needed to be done in the gestureHold otherwise it would continue to fire myEdit on the invoked item because of the way the gesture is attached to the item the first time it is run.